# systemd error “failed to start service: unit service is not loaded properly: exec format error”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, systemd

I am trying to create and start a service in a Ubuntu VM, I have written a service creation and installation service randn.sh and a service script . The service generates a random number between 1-20 .  When I start the service using 'systemctl randn start " it shows the error: 
Unit Randn.service is not loaded properly : Exec format error. My randn.service script is

```
[Unit]
Description = Randn daemon
After network.target = auditd.service

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/ start randn.sh
ExecStop = /usr/local/bin/ stop randn.sh
Restart = always

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Can someone what am I doing wrong ? Is the syntax of .service file is wrong or something else in script.sh ? 
I am new to this, please help a noob out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces between the options and commands in the Unit file:

**Incorrect**:

```
ExecStart = /some/command
# This should not include spaces!
```

**Correct**:

```
ExecStart=/some/command
```

Comment: @I'L'I

Could you help with 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671161/unit-xxx-service-is-not-loaded-properly-exec-format-error-on-ubuntu18-04-creat