# Unit service is not loaded properly: Exec format error. on ubuntu18.04 creating .net service

Tags: ubuntu, service, ubuntu-18.04, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to create a service to run by .net application on ubuntu 18.04.

cd /lib/systemd/system/YellowPages.service

```
[Unit]
Description = Yellow pages .NET service

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/yp_app
ExecStart=dotnet /home/yp_app/YellowPages.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~
```

I have my application on /home/yp_app.

when I run:systemd start YellowPages.service
I get
Excess arguments.

so I tried with: systemctl start YellowPages.service
I get

```
 Failed to start YellowPages.service: Unit YellowPages.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status YellowPages.service' for details.
```

When I look into  cat /var/log/syslog

I could see

```
systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/YellowPages.service:7: Executable path is not 
absolute: dotnet /home/yp_app/YellowPages.dll
```

I am new to Linux I am wondering where I am wrong.
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: @Chris Williams

Comment: Please post the result of this command: `which dotnet`

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues with your daemon:

```
[Unit]
Description = Yellow pages .NET service
```

Remove spaces around equal sign:

```
[Unit]
Description=Yellow pages .NET service
```

`ExecStart` needs an absolute path (hence the error):

```
[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/yp_app/YellowPages.dll
```

Your `dotnet` executable might be located elsewhere, although you can find out its absolute path by doing:

```
$ which dotnet
```

Whatever is returned would be the absolute path to use.

Comment: did the changes not getting that error no more .
But when I try to enable the service by: 

systemctl enable YellowPages.service:

Failed to enable unit: Invalid argument

Comment: when I check the syslogs i see:

CRON[8868]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)

Comment: @sumanthshetty: Show the command you are attempting to start the service. It should simply be: `systemctl start Yellowpages`. The second comment with the `cron` error is unrelated. If it doesn’t work use `journalctl -xe` immediately after and post the output.

Comment: @I'L'I 
i used systemctl start Yellowpages.service 
Failed to start YellowPages.service: Unit YellowPages.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status YellowPages.service' for details.

when I check the syslog 

/lib/systemd/system/YellowPages.service:7: Working directory path 'home/yp_app' is not absolute.

how do I find the absolute path of the app folder. i sued  PWD

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `/` at the beginning of `home/ypp...`. When you are on the working directory try: `pwd`, it should return the full absolute path.